# Why ggplot plotting for some periods every five year and for other one every two years?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, x-axis

[image]

this is my second time asking question here. I hope I do it in a right way!
I am plotting three subset of my data with ggplot and I am not putting any command for x-axis like every two years or something. My subsets data set are same size(they are 10 years long) but it gives me for two of them on x-axis every 5 years and for one every two years. how can I have same x-axis?

here is my code:

```
before2000<- wml%>%
  filter(between(YYYYMM, 193001, 193912))

before2000$YYYYMM<-  parse_date(as.character( before2000$YYYYMM), "%Y%m")
before2000$WML<-cumprod( before2000$WML+1)
before2000$WMLScaled<-cumprod( before2000$MOM_BS+1)
before2000<-before2000%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(WML,WMLScaled), 
               names_to = "key", values_to = "values")

ggplot(data =before2000, aes(x= YYYYMM, y=values, color= key ))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = "Panel A: Riskmanaged momentum: 1930:01 to 1939:12",
       y="Cumlative Return", x="")+
  theme_classic()



after2000<- wml%>%
  filter(between(YYYYMM, 200001, 201012))

after2000$YYYYMM<-  parse_date(as.character( after2000$YYYYMM), "%Y%m")
after2000$WML<-cumprod( after2000$WML+1)
after2000$WMLScaled<-cumprod( after2000$MOM_BS+1)
after2000<-after2000%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(WML,WMLScaled), 
               names_to = "key", values_to = "values")

ggplot(data =after2000, aes(x= YYYYMM, y=values, color= key))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = "Panel B: Riskmanaged momentum: 2000:01 to 2010:12",
       y="Cumlative Return", x="")+
  theme_classic()


after2010<- wml%>%
  filter(between(YYYYMM, 201101, 202012))

after2010$YYYYMM<-  parse_date(as.character( after2010$YYYYMM), "%Y%m")
after2010$WML<-cumprod( after2010$WML+1)
after2010$WMLScaled<-cumprod( after2010$MOM_BS+1)
after2010<-after2010%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(WML,WMLScaled), 
               names_to = "key", values_to = "values")

ggplot(data =after2010, aes(x= YYYYMM, y=values, color= key ))+
  geom_line()+
  labs(title = "Panel C: Riskmanaged momentum: 2011:01 to 2020:12",
       y="Cumlative Return", x="")+
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: You didn't supply any data, so your problem isn't reproducible. However, you likely just need to add `scale_x_date()` with an appropriate `date_breaks` argument. So e.g. `+ scale_x_date(date_breaks = "2 years")`. See `?scale_x_date`.

Comment: Thanks a lot . Now it gives me two years but with this on x-Axis "YYY-MM-DD".

Comment: Read `?scale_x_date` and the linked `?strptime`. You can define the `date_labels` argument, e.g. `date_labels = '%Y' should give only the year (including century).